# How do I stop the zoom in motion in my expanding cards web dev mini project?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to stop the zoom in motion of the images when I just want the panels to expand and fill the new space with the rest of the image.

I tried by changing the values of background-size, background-position, background-repeat to see if the rest of the panels behaved like the first one.

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')

panels.forEach(panel => {
  panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeActiveClasses()
    panel.classList.add('active')
  })
})

function removeActiveClasses() {
  panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.classList.remove('active')
  })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 85vh;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0.5;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-in;
}

.panel h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
  flex: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.panel.active h3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.4s;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .panel:nth-of-type(4),
  .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url(/images/Black\ Sand\ Beach\ Reynisfjara\,\ Iceland.jpg);">
    <h3>Black Sand Beach</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/Beach\ Resorts\,\ Maldives.jpg);">
    <h3>Beach Resorts</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/Mt.Fuji\,\ Japan.jpg);">
    <h3>Mt.Fuji</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/Pyramids\ of\ Giza\,\ Egypt.jpg);">
    <h3>Pyramids of Giza</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="panel" style="background-image: url(/images/Victoria\ Falls\,\ Zambia.jpg);">
    <h3>Victoria Falls</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet try using https://pen.new/ , the code you provided seems not working for what your issue stands for, and thx 

Comment: @DevAbdoTolba No need since the question has the ability to create a runnable example in it using a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which size images you are using, but I think that may be where this is going wrong. I tried to reproduce your code here. Try changing your source images to some images that are much wider than the ones you are using now. Hope this will help you on your way. Have a great day!

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')

panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeActiveClasses()
        panel.classList.add('active')
    })
})

function removeActiveClasses() {
    panels.forEach(panel => {
        panel.classList.remove('active')
    })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 85vh;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0.5;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-in;  
}

.panel h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active {
    flex: 5;
    position: relative;
}

.panel.active h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.4s;
}
  
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
      width: 100vw;
    }
  
    .panel:nth-of-type(4),
    .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">

        <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/1/1500/500');">
            <h3>Black Sand Beach</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/2/1500/500');">
            <h3>Beach Resorts</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/3/1500/500');">
            <h3>Mt.Fuji</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/4/1500/500');">
            <h3>Pyramids of Giza</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/5/1500/500');">
            <h3>Victoria Falls</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I fixed the ratio of the images, and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Can you accept this answer then so that the case is closed?

Comment: Yes. I can, and I did. Thank you for being patient and kind!